# Fusion of two neutrinos

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos

What are the results of fusing an electron neutrino and a muon neutrino? If you have an answer, then why? I looked this up and searched for stuff on Google, Wikipedia and a few other sites, but all the results say are stuff on nuclear fusion and neutrinos.

**BONUS QUESTION:** 

What happens if you put another muon neutrino into the mix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such tree-level interaction in the conventional theory.

But then free-propagating neutrinos are not in pure flavor states except by chance anyway, so any pair of neutrino and anti-neutrino<sup>1</sup> could participate in a vertex
$$ \nu_l + \bar\nu_l \to Z^0 \,,$$
which is roughly equivalent to Drell-Yan in the charged lepton sector with a projection into agreeing flavor states ($l$) built into the operator.

The cross-section will be very low and the $Z$ will have to decay to something on-shell very quickly so there are energy and momentum conservation requirements.

---

<sup>1</sup> If neutrinos really are Majorana as in the theory the identification of anti- and normal- is frame dependent.